# Threading.task and Dispatcher.Invoke method in the Window Close event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, task, dispatcher

I want to perform series of operations synchronously while closing my MVVM based WPF Application.

Right now I am using Task and `Dispatcher.Invoke` within the tasks to show the message to the user.

The issue is that when i used `Dispatcher.Invoke` method in the `myfunction` function, application gets stuck there. I know this function is working properly when I used these function other than closed event.

So is there any issue of using the `Dispatcher.Invoke` method in the Close event os the application. How can i solve this?

```
/// <summary>
/// Main window closing
/// </summary>
private void MainWindowClosing(object args)
{
     var task1 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
         myfunction();
     }).ContinueWith((cc) => {  });
     task1.Wait();
}

private void myfunction()
{
    //my serries of operation will come here.
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }));   
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blocking UI Thread in MVVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833759/blocking-ui-thread-in-mvvm)

Answer (score 3):

You are **creating a [Deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) here**. It won't work even when you put the code in button click handler.

### REASON

You are creating a task and waiting on task using `task1.Wait()`. Hence *UI dispatcher is waiting for task to complete* before it can process any further messages.

At same time you are *invoking one operation on UI dispatcher from task* that too synchronously here

```
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("test");
            }));
```

but since UI dispatcher is still waiting on task to complete, you can't invoke any method synchronously on it. Hence the ***DEADLOCK*** (waiting on each other).

### Possible Solution

If you want to invoke task synchronously and that too without closing window, you can achieve that  using following steps:

1. First of all remove the *task1.Wait()*. (do not block UI dispatcher)
2. Second, maintain bool to keep count that close event has been initiated.
3. Last, cancel closing event by setting `e.Cancel = true` and manually raise close event from task itself once you finished.

***Relevant code:***

```
    bool closeInitiated = false;
    private void poc_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!closeInitiated)
        {
            var task1 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                myfunction();
            }).ContinueWith((cc) => { });
            closeInitiated = true;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    private void myfunction()
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("test");
                Close();
            }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is at task1.Wait(); Go through this [UI Thread Wait and DeadLock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx)

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten the same issue, and I figured the problem was that the Task where I'm invoking to, was already closed a second after clicking the Close button, so when the Invoking function takes a bit longer - it might crash.

If you still wanna execute this function, I used `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` and it worked.

Here is my code:

```
if (app.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) //doesn't need to be invoked
    myFunction();
    else //coming from another thread need invoker
    {
        //at exiting program this task might already be canceled, so make sure it's not
        if (!app.Current.Dispatcher.HasShutdownFinished) 
            app.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(myFunction());
        else   
            app.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(myFunction());
```